# Graphing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a stress strain diagram in Excel, and I am getting a weird result.   Excel is plotting the data, and plotting a line from the last data point back to the origin.

Can anyone help me get rid of this extra line?  I watched a bunch of videos on how to make stress strain plots and none of them have had this problem.

Here is a picture of the error:

[image: pic]

Here is a picture of some of the data points at the end of the list. The column on the left is strain (x), and the column on the right is stress (y):

[image: pic]

Comment: -1. Its not the problem with Excel but with your data. If you read the last data point, its quite self-explanatory! Btw, why is your strain negative?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the raw data, it looks like the last data point is 0,0 it might be possible for a blank or null entry to cause this too, don't know for sure without checking.

Can you post an extract of your data with the all important last few entries?

UPDATE:

Ah the last entry has a tiny x value and a relatively small negative y. The Y scale is pretty small so the -122 doesn't really show up and x is as close to 0 as makes no difference so that is where the final point is displayed.

I would recommend excluding the final point as an invalid outlier.

Comment: 0.238000129 90866.99623
0.239500129 90412.66125
0.24080013 89958.32627
0.242100131 89958.32627
0.243500131 89503.99129
0.245000132 89049.65631
0.246300133 89049.65631
0.247500134 88595.32133
0.249000134 88140.98635
0.250600135 87686.65137
0.251800136 87686.65137
0.253200137 87232.31639
0.254600137 86777.9814
0.256000138 86323.64642
0.257300139 85869.31144
0.25880014 85869.31144
0.260300141 85414.97646
0.261600141 84960.64148
0.262800142 84506.3065
0.264400143 83597.63654
8.12993E-05 -122.2161099

Comment: sorry the two columns did not paste nicely.  Let me post a picture

Comment: I added a picture to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem you are having be due to that last row, the second column has a negative value? it appears to go from 83597.63654 to -122.2161099, this would make your line look like it is returning to the origin but is crossing very close to 0,0.